# equals() and operator "==" in java

Tags: java, equals

I know that `equals()` will compare the value of objects, the '==' operator will check if the variable point to the same memory.

I do not understand how `equals()` compare the value of objects, for example:

```
class Test {
    public Test(int x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int x,
    float y;
}

Test test1 = new Test(1,2.0);
Test test2 = new Test(1,2.0);
```

So if I use `equals()`, will it compare each properties in each object?

And what about if we are talking about String? using equals() and operator “==”, do we still need to override the equals()?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, if you don't override the `equals`-method in your class, then `equals` is the same as `==`. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for this:

> The equals method for class Object
>   implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on
>   objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method
>   returns true if and only if x and y
>   refer to the same object (x == y has
>   the value true).

The documentation also states what requirements there are for `equals` methods in case you want to implement it.

Comment: Yes, the `equals` method is inherited in this case from `Object` which  has the following implementation: `public boolean equals(Object obj){return this==obj;}`

Answer (score 11):

Not unless you overload it properly according to the rules laid down by [Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf).

The default behavior checks equality of references using `==`.

It's important to override `equals` *and* `hashCode` for your objects, especially if you intend to use them in java.util.Collections.

Comment: +1, but you might want to refer to the rules set in the standard instead of some random guy...

Comment: Some random guy?  I take it you don't know who Joshua Bloch is.  The citation IS the standard.  He's the guy who wrote the java.util Collections.

Comment: @duffymo: I don't think `equals` is defined in `java.util.Collections`. And whoever he is, he's certainly more random than the Java standard.

Comment: Matti, it's time to quit.  I didn't say that equals was defined in java.util.Collections; it's required for all objects that are inserted into Collection classes.  And Joshua Bloch wrote that standard when he was Distinguished Engineer at Sun (now Chief Java Architect at Google).

Comment: @duffymo: I still consider any individual (whether he was a "Distinguished Engineer" or had some other silly title) more random than an official standard.

Comment: What if that 'random' individual actually conceived of and wrote the standard that you are citing?  Does that make him silly?

Comment: @duffymo: Standards are a group effort. I'm sure there were many others involved.

Comment: LOL!  You keep thinking that, Matti.  Can't admit you're wrong, can you?  It's nice to be 22 and infallible.

Comment: @duffymo: I shall. You should try thinking once in a while too! Might help you get rid of your tendency to idolize people.

Comment: I'm not idolizing anybody, just stating a fact.

Comment: @duffymo: Sometimes which facts you decide to state is more important than whether they're actually facts or not.

Comment: I'm neither interested in nor able to convince you of anything.  Why don't you grab a copy of "Effective Java" and decide for yourself whether Joshua Bloch is a random guy or if his knowledge of Java is worth emulating?  Or don't - I could care less what you do.

Comment: @duffymo: He might not be as random as most people, but as I've already stated, more random than an official standard. It's a relative thing.

Comment: @duffymo @MattiVirkkunen Please take it elsewhere

Comment: SO needs a way to allow trusted users to delete comments.

Answer (score 0):

The equals method is defined in class Object, and since all objects in Java implicitly or explicitly inherit from this class, they too will inherit the equals() method as implemented by Object. The default implementation in Object will simply return true if the objects pass the "==" condition.

However, you are free to override the equals() method in your own class and specify the criteria which must be checked to see if two objects are meaningfully equal. For example, you might say that two instances are only equal if each of its attributes contain the same values as another object, or you might instead want to simply check a few attributes which make up the objects "business key" and ignore the others.

The equality of String classes follow the same rules as any other class in Java; "==" will be true if they do refer to the same instance, and equals() will be true if they contain the same values.

Comment: All of the answers are saying the same thing. This is a basic concept of Java and you would do very well to understand it completely.