# == or equals when comparing final static fields

Tags: java, operators, equals

I've returned back to *Java* after a little break with *C#* and I'm already tired of writing stuff like `a.equals(b)` so I was wondering if is there a way to use the `==` operator without breaking my program.

Here's my situation:

```
public static class A {
    public final static A STATIC_FIELD = new A(prop1, prop2);

    public A method(int param){
        return (param > 0.5) ? STATIC_FIELD : new A(prop1, prop2);
    }
}
```

Now, can I replace `equals` with `==` in the following snippet since I'm referring to the same object or is it wrong?

```
....
private bool method(){
    A aInstance = getAInstance();
    int param = Math.Random();
    return aInstance.method(param).equals(A.STATIC_FIELD);
}
....
```

And what if the `STATIC_FIELD` in a value taken from an `enum`?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what do you want to do.

If you need to check if this is exactly the same object, use the direct comparison. If you need to check if the object wraps the same content (like string or number), then .equals should be used.

Most common errors with these methods seem coming from string comparison, where .equals returns true if the strings have the same content but == only returns true if this is the same instance of string.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid == (ok, let's agree that you know it :-)), also in relation to singleton instances as you may "forget" later that it is created via singleton. But I will give you a hint. Instead of:

```
if ((var != null) && (var.equals(A.STATIC_FIELD)))
```

you may write:

```
if (A.STATIC_FIELD.equals(var))
```

just like many people do not realize that to compare strings they may use:

```
if ("static string".equals(varString))
```

You may also use  java.util.Objects.equals to compare objects without all this checking nulls burden.

Comment: Nah, its a basic one and not related to the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

`==` checks if two objects are the same instance. If you want to check if two variables are holding the same instance (as they may well be if you are assigning your variables to class constants), `==` is fine to use. It also won't error if your variable happens to hold `null`, so it has that benefit over `.equals()`.

Instances of an `enum` are always constant, and two *different* instances will never be equal, so `==` is fine to use for those too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't override the equals() method, `equals()` and `==` do the same thing, check the equality of the references. You can make the replacement in this case, since method() will return the same reference as A.STATIC_FIELD when it is true. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848370/equals-and-operator-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

no you cant use == instead of equals() becuase when we use == in java we are actually comparing the memory address of the object , so if the method returns STATIC_FIELD then it will work properly as its a static object and the address will be same everywhere.
But when method will return new object of A then the address wont match even if the content is same within the class because the new A(param1, param2) insists JVM to create a new object at a different memory location

Comment: But here, method() does not return a new instance of A (when true), it returns the static field.

Comment: method will return STATIC_FIELD only when the param value is greater than .5 otherwise it will return a new object

Comment: if u think it will always be true then u can use ==. But its always better to use equals with objects

Comment: Since he hasn't overridden equals() in his class, its immaterial. == will work in the code given and provide the expected results. He is not trying to compare the value of the new A which is created.